# How to get nodes from XML file without its attribute and put to a List of string

Tags: c#, xml, list

I would like to display the tag names of child nodes without its attributes. Then those tag names (nodes) should be put in a `List` of string. Here's example of my XML file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ROOT>
    <CAR>
        <ID>21</ID>
        <MANUFACTURER>Ford</MANUFACTURER>
        <MODEL>Fiesta</MODEL>
    </CAR>
    <CAR>
        <ID>22</ID>
        <MANUFACTURER>Peugeot</MANUFACTURER>
        <MODEL>508</MODEL>
    </CAR>
</ROOT>
```

So, the effect I want to get in a console output is shown below:

```
ID
MANUFACTURER
MODEL
```

Then I would like to store that ID, MANUFACTURER and MODEL tag names in a `List` of strings.

This is the code that I tried so far:

```cs
            XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDocument.PreserveWhitespace = true;
            try
            {
                xmlDocument.Load("XMLFile.xml");
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }

            Console.WriteLine(xmlDocument.OuterXml);

            XmlNodeList nodeList = xmlDocument.SelectNodes("ROOT/CAR");
            foreach(XmlNode node in nodeList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(node.ChildNodes);
                xmlNodes.Add(node.ChildNodes.ToString());
            }
```

The problem is that it's not displaying the way I want to. As a result I only get two `System.Xml.XmlChildNodes` which seems to be corresponding to two `<CAR>` nodes, instead of its three child nodes, such as ID, MANUFACTURER and MODEL.

```
System.Xml.XmlChildNodes
System.Xml.XmlChildNodes
```

Adding items to a List basically adds the same thing as shown above.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you want to add to the List, the values  of tags or tags name ``ID MANUFACTURER MODEL``?

Comment: Not values, just tag names.

Comment: i have added an answer, can you check it and let me know, if it's work well for you.

Comment: Thank you, I’ll try your code when I’ll get back to computer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have to use XmlDocument, then you can -

```
List<string> elements = new List<string>();
XmlNodeList CarNodes = xml.SelectNodes("Root/Car");
foreach(XmlNode c in CarNodes)
{
    foreach(XmlNode n in c.ChildNodes)
    {
        if (!elements.Contains(n.Name))
        {
            elements.Add(n.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

But I find **XDocument** to be much simpler and better readability.

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(yourXmlString);
List<string> elements = xdoc.Descendants("Car")
                            .DescendantNodes().OfType<XElement>()
                            .Select(x => x.Name).Distinct().ToList();
```

And thats all you'll need. Easy to read as well, get all the descendants of "Car" Node and get all distinct names of XElements within it.

Another way to do it -

```
List<string> elements = xdoc.Descendants("Car").First()
                            .DescendantNodes().OfType<XElement>()
                            .Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
```

In this case I have removed the "distinct" and rather got just the first Car node *ONLY*. You can see the difference - if by any case some other Car node has an extra element, you'll miss getting that information by doing it this way.

Comment: This is the answer that suits my needs perfectly. Though I'm used to using XmlDocument, the XDocument is also a really nice way.

Answer (score 2):

You could loop through for children nodes:

1- You can define `xmlNodes` like a `HashSet` to avoid multiple tags like :

```
HashSet<string> xmlNodes = new HashSet<string>();
```

2 - Change little the code like :

```
....
XmlNodeList nodeList = xmlDocument.SelectNodes("ROOT/CAR");
foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
{
    foreach(XmlNode element in node.ChildNodes)
    {
        if (element.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
            xmlNodes.Add(element.Name);
    }
}
```

**Demo**

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", xmlNodes));
```

**Result**

```
ID, MANUFACTURER, MODEL
```

I hope you find this helpful.

Comment: I tried your code and it does work as intended, so thank you for help!